# Не удается установить пакет RJDemetra

Tags: python, r, google-colaboratory

Требуется установить пакет `RJDemetra` в google colab. Пакет для языка `R`, поэтому использую питоновскую оболочку с помощью библиотеки `rpy2`.

Для работы этого пакета так же должен быть установлен еще `rJava`

```
library(rJava)
>>> StrVector with 9 elements.
'rJava' 'tools' 'stats' ... 'datasets'  'methods'   'base'
```

Но когда запускаю следующие команды

```
r('''
    install.packages("RJDemetra", destdir='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library')
    devtools::install_github("jdemetra/rjdemetra")
  ''')
```

то начинается бесконечная работа команды, без завершения, после 30 минут работы я сама выключаю, потому что эти команды не могут так долго работать.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?